# Why is my e-mail address flagged as "temporary"?

Tags: support, email, accounts

I registered for Stack Overflow just last week, but had to fall back on a different e-mail address, because the registration process gave me the error message "We do not allow temporary e-mail addresses. Please try again with a different address."

My e-mail address is at a vanity domain—in the .net TLD, with a hyphen as part of the name, but otherwise pretty vanilla—but it's in no way "temporary": I've been using it for a solid twelve years.

Are there criteria used to designate "temporary"? Might they need review?

Comment: My guess is that it's dumbly regexed in one way or another. They want some assurance that you didn't create a new email address just to sign up with, and *they have no means of knowing* how long you've actually had it; the goal is to filter out services that are useful for that purpose.

Comment: *"Might they need review?"* You may well be best off contacting [so] directly.

Comment: Having trouble digging up a proper reference, but I'm pretty sure "temporary email" in this context refers to sites like <https://10minutemail.com/>, which will create an _extremely_ temporary email to use, rather than an actual user creating a "temporary" email on some standard email hosting service. I recall a post (probably on MSE) talking about blocking these sorts of services from creating accounts for spam-prevention reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have had blocks in place for common "disposable" email addresses for quite some time to hamper spammers and trolls from using unverified email addresses to create accounts on the network. Personal email addresses - *shouldn't* be getting blocked by these. The only thing I could imagine is if your website URL contains the URL of one of these sites.

Without knowing that email address, it'd be difficult for me to check why it was blocked, though. As mentioned by Thom A in the comments, I recommend you contact our support team directly ("[Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)" at the bottom of any page) and ask for it to be checked out. You may be able to add that email address as a login at this point if you want to switch your verified email to it, so feel free to try that if you don't want to keep your current email.

Also, regardless of your personal willingness, I would discourage you from posting your domain or full email here. The Support team will be better able to help you with this situation - feel free to reference this meta post and my response.